# sprintf() function not giving the desired output

Tags: c

This is a small portion of code that splits variables into characters, all of the characters are then placed in sequence in a buffer. I have managed to get that part to work but I am having some issues with the sprintf function. The signed integer Cur_Scale is not outputting the correct characters.

I have tried modifying the formatting specifiers but always get a similar output. The only way I get the correct value is if I place a "-" in front of the argument / the variable.

I'm sure it's something very easy I'm overlooking but just can not spot it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t Seconds_Timer = 123456789;
int32_t Cur_Scale = -254123678;
uint8_t buffer[250];
uint8_t buffer_2[20];

int main()
{          
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);       // Set all buffer to zero 
            memset(buffer_2, 0, sizeof buffer_2);   // Set all buffer_2 to zero 
            sprintf(buffer_2, "%ld", Seconds_Timer); // This will put up to 9 characters in buffer
            //Split the variable into characters
            
            uint8_t a;
            uint8_t b;
            
            for(a=0; a<=8; a++) 
                {
                buffer[a]=buffer_2[a];
                }
            
            memset(buffer_2, 0, sizeof buffer_2);   // Set all buffer_2 to zero 
            sprintf(buffer_2, "%ld", Cur_Scale); // This will put up to 10 characters in buffer
            
            for(a=9,b=0; a<=18; a++,b++)    
                {
                buffer[a]=buffer_2[b];
                }
            printf(buffer, 20);     // Send confirmed value back in characters    
}
```

Comment: Is `int32_t ` large enough to store the number

Comment: What output are you expecting to see?  What output do you actually see instead?

Comment: `int main()`  Is it 1993, or is this C++?  For modern C, use `int main(void)`

Comment: 32 bit is 4,294,967,295 in decimal, so large enough. Don't worry I don't use int main() in my programs, but I use an online complier for convenience as it's quicker than my IDE for testing small sections, it defaults to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your expected output: 123456789-254123678

Then a code then works like this:

```cpp
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int32_t Seconds_Timer = 123456789;
int32_t Cur_Scale = -254123678;
char buffer[250];
char buffer_2[20];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);      // Set all buffer to zero
  memset(buffer_2, 0, sizeof buffer_2);  // Set all buffer_2 to zero
  sprintf(buffer_2, "%d",
          Seconds_Timer);  // This will put up to 9 characters in buffer
  // Split the variable into characters

  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t b;

  for (a = 0; a <= 8; a++) {
    buffer[a] = buffer_2[a];
  }

  memset(buffer_2, 0, sizeof buffer_2);  // Set all buffer_2 to zero
  sprintf(buffer_2, "%d",
          Cur_Scale);  // This will put up to 10 characters in buffer

  for (a = 9, b = 0; a <= 18; a++, b++) {
    buffer[a] = buffer_2[b];
  }
  printf("%s\n", buffer);  // Send confirmed value back in characters

  return 0;
}
```

For your original code, the compiler warning gives many hints, fix them will correct the code.

- `uint8_t buffer[250];` should be `char buffer[250];`
- `sprintf(buffer_2, "%ld", Seconds_Timer);` should be `sprintf(buffer_2, "%d", Seconds_Timer);`, ld is for long int type
- `printf(buffer, 20);` should be `printf("%s\n", buffer);`, buffer is not a literal format string

Comment: I realised my mistake was using ld and not d, thanks for pointing that out. The rest is fine as my buffers use a combination of both integers and characters, the sprintf converts the integer into characters, the correct output.